# Facebook Plugin to show visitors comments on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, review

Which Facebook plugin do i need to use for my website,that would let visitors make comments/reviews and those comments are shown on my Facebook Business page.

I have already tried the Comments Plugin but that is showing the comment to the person profile that has left the review.

Comment: In which programming language are you going to build your website?

Comment: Hi, Ill be building in .NET

Answer (score 1):

well if you are using Wordpress,you may use Wordpress plugin provided by Facebook itself.Another chance is you are not using Wordpress ,then you either need to develop your own application for this,or you can use a third party app.You may find a nice app here:
[link](http://www.faceitpages.com/facebook-application/embed-website/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, if I didnt want to use the third party app, what would be the process that I would need to develop please

Comment: The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}